Store value in AndroidKeyStore with BIOMETRIC_WEAK returns UserNotAuthenticated
I'm trying to store a value in AndroidKeyStore, but I'm getting a UserNotAuthenticated when I use BIOMETRIC_WEAK. With BIOMETRIC_STRONG there are no issues.
BiometricPrompt
mBiometricPromptInfoWeakAuth = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                    .setTitle(biometricPromptTitle)
                    .setDescription(biometricPromptSubtitle)
                    .setAllowedAuthenticators(Authenticators.BIOMETRIC_WEAK | Authenticators.DEVICE_CREDENTIAL)
                    .build();

Method used to save values
BiometricUtils.launchBiometricPromptEncrypt(new BiometricPromptEncryptListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFinished(String dat, String iv) {
                    sharedPreferencesManager.save(SharedPreferencesManager.getStringIvForWeakProtection(key), iv);
                    sharedPreferencesManager.save(SharedPreferencesManager.getStringDatForWeakProtection(key), dat);
                    listener.onSuccessful();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(SiaKeystoreInternalError error) {
                    listener.onFailure(error);
                }
            }, mContext, key, value, userAuthValiditySeconds, mBiometricPromptInfoWeakAuth);

Method to launch BiometricPrompt
public static void launchBiometricPromptEncrypt(BiometricPromptEncryptListener listener, Context context, String keyAlias, char[] value, int validationTimeout, BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo promptInfo) {

        ShowBiometricPromptActivityListener showBiometricPromptlistener = new ShowBiometricPromptActivityListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccessful() {

                BiometricPromptListener biometricPromptListener = new BiometricPromptListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(@NonNull BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult result) {
                        try {
                            Cipher cipher;
                            if (result.getCryptoObject() != null)
                                cipher = result.getCryptoObject().getCipher();
                            else
                                cipher = CryptographicUtils.getEncryptCipher(context, keyAlias, true, validationTimeout);


                            String dat = CryptographicUtils.encryptData(value, cipher);
                            String iv = CryptographicUtils.getIV(cipher);
                            listener.onFinished(dat, iv);
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            listener.onError(new SiaKeystoreInternalError(SiaKeystoreInternalError.KEYSTORE_INTERNAL_ERROR, "", ex.getMessage()));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(SiaKeystoreInternalError error) {
                        listener.onError(error);
                    }
                };

                BiometricPrompt biometricPrompt = generateBiometricPrompt(biometricPromptListener, context);

                try {
                    if (promptInfo.getAllowedAuthenticators() == BIOMETRIC_STRONG ) {
                        //Authenticate with BIOMETRIC_STRONG
                        Cipher cipher = CryptographicUtils.getEncryptCipher(context, keyAlias, true, -1);
                        BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject cryptoObject = new BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(cipher);
                        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, cryptoObject);
                    }
                    else {
                        //Authenticate with BIOMETRIC_WEAK and/or CREDENTIALS
                        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo);
                    }
                } catch ( Exception e) {
                    NavigationUtils.finishHostTransparentFragmentActivity();
                    listener.onError(new SiaKeystoreInternalError(SiaKeystoreInternalError.KEYSTORE_INTERNAL_ERROR, "", e.getMessage()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SiaKeystoreInternalError error) {
                    listener.onError(error);
            }
        };

        showBiometricPromptActivity(showBiometricPromptlistener, context, promptInfo);

    }

Method getEncryptCipher
public static Cipher getEncryptCipher(Context context, String keyAlias, boolean userAuthenticationRequired, int validationTimeout) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, InvalidKeyException {
    CryptographicUtils.generateBiometricKey(context, keyAlias, userAuthenticationRequired, validationTimeout);
    Cipher res = Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
            + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
            + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    SecretKey secretKey = getSecretKey(keyAlias);
    res.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return res;
}

Method generateBiometricKey
public static void generateBiometricKey(Context context, String keyAlias, boolean userAuthenticationRequired, int validationTimeout) {
try {
    KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            keyAlias,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT);

    spec.setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC);
    spec.setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    spec.setKeySize(256);
    spec.setUserAuthenticationRequired(userAuthenticationRequired);
    spec.setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(validationTimeout);
    spec.setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(userAuthenticationRequired);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        boolean hasStrongBox = context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_STRONGBOX_KEYSTORE);
        spec.setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256);
        spec.setIsStrongBoxBacked(hasStrongBox);
    }

    generateSecretKey(spec.build());

} catch (NoSuchProviderException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context,
            "Authentication error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            .show();
}

}
When this line is executed
String dat = CryptographicUtils.encryptData(value, cipher);

inside launchBiometricPromptEncrypt->BiometricPromptListener->onAuthenticationSucceeded()
I'm getting the next exception:
android.security.KeyStoreException: Key user not authenticated (internal Keystore code: -26 message: In KeystoreOperation::update

Caused by:
    0: In update: Trying to get auth tokens.
    1: In AuthInfo::get_auth_tokens.
    2: In get_auth_tokens: No operation auth token received.
    3: Error::Km(ErrorCode(-26))) (public error code: 2 internal Keystore code: -26)"

I'm very lost with this issue, with fingerprint runs well, but with face not. I'm using Samsung S20 Ultra with Android v13. But some other devices that I can test is facing the same problem.
Thank you for any advice
